# Python Pandas Dataframe - Cut specific part of string, when length to long

Tags: python, pandas, web-crawler

I'm working on a web-crawler in python for my tennisclub to save game-result, ranks etc. from a webpage in my database (to then show it on my own website). Works just fine, I get tables like this:

[image]

However, some team-names are way to long to output them nicely on my website (especially when two clubs together).

[image]

My question is: how can I cut everything behind the "/" with pandas if a string reaches a certain length, like 34.

My code so far (with other, working, changes to the crawled information):

```
for x in range(len(teams)):
     driver.get('https://baden.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa  
     /wa/teamPortrait?team=' + teams[x][1])
     table_games = driver.page_source

     df = pd.read_html(table_games)[1]

     banned = ['TSG']
     f = lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in banned])
     df["Heimmannschaft"] = df["Heimmannschaft"].apply(f)
     df["Gastmannschaft"] = df["Gastmannschaft"].apply(f)


     df = df.rename(columns={'Datum, Uhrzeit.1': 'Termin'})
     df[['Datum', 'Uhrzeit']] = df.Termin.str.split(" ", expand=True, )
     del df['Termin']
     df = df[['Datum', 'Uhrzeit', 'Heimmannschaft', 'Gastmannschaft', 'Matches',                  
     'Spielbericht']]

     df.to_sql(con=con, name=teams[x][0]+'_Spiele', if_exists='replace')



     driver.get('https://baden.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa
     /wa/groupPage?targetFed=BAD&championship=B1+S+2021&group=' + teams[x][2])
     table_ranks = driver.page_source

     df = pd.read_html(table_ranks)[0]

     f = lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in banned])
     df["Mannschaft"] = df["Mannschaft"].apply(f)

     df.iloc[0:, 1:].to_sql(con=con, name=teams[x][0]+ '_Tabelle', if_exists='replace')

driver.quit()
```

The driver in my code-example crawls to different websites for ranks **and** game-days and in both cases are some team-names way to long (so I want to cut the second team-name, beginning at the "/").

I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: So you want to cut each name at certain fixed length or after '/'?

Comment: After the "/", when the string is longer than e.g. 34. So if I have like "TC Germania 1890 Großsachsen/KSV 1948 St**einklingen**", which is way to long (bold letters are e.g. over the limit), I do not want to cut it exactly at the 35 letter but at the "/". In this case, it is like just one team would play.

Comment: And if there are no "/", then cut it at 34 length?

Comment: Would be reasonable, but there are no teams who have more than 34 letters (only when two teams play together).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that length would be more than `34` only if there are more than `1` team, so simple solution would be to check the length first, if more than `34`, then do a `split` at `/` and get the first team:

```
df['your_column'] = df['your_column'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0] if len(x) > 34 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only split and get the first team if length > 34

```
df['your_column'] = df['your_column'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0] if len(x) > 34 else x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Your code makes sense to me, but I get two syntax errors: one after "34?" and one at the end of the line.

Comment: Oops sorry the logic is the same but I changed the syntax to make sense in python (earlier syntax was ternary operators which is prevalent in other languages to do the same task). Hope this works for you

Comment: But now your answer is exactly same as the one I already posted.